# FPC design Flex PCB

Tags: pcb, eaglecad, fpc

I want to design a flex PCB to stick a membrane keypad onto the back of a regular PCB. We want the two sections: one for power, LEDs, etc., and one flex PCB for just the keys.

How may I design the FPC connector in AutoCAD Eagle/Fusion 360 electronics? How can I show the 30 wires needed to fit FFC & FPC Connectors 0.5MM 30P R/A Socket SMT GOLD?

Is there a way to show the stiffener on the end of the wires to connect to this item:
https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Hirose-Connector/FH28E-30S-0.5SH05?qs=nSryOFbzj8KaotUrp2wRmw%3D%3D
[image]

This is the connector/part of flex PCB that I don't know how to make. Is this part of the schematic file or the PCB file?

Comment: This thread may give you some clues: https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/eagle-forum/flex-pcb-design-with-eagle/td-p/9376159

Comment: I think the big issue is I can find Items that connect to this here: https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Samtec/FJH-30-D-04.00-4?qs=Cqqh%252BS766wn%252B9tkx5Hh3dQ%3D%3D

But nothing on landpatterns, etc. Like that is flex pcb with the fingers and stiffener. How can I either integrate that into my fpcb, or create it on my own?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is create a footprint. Specify the stiffener location with the manufacturer. https://www.reddit.com/r/PrintedCircuitBoard/comments/4zuue3/eagle_help_with_fpc_connector/

MY issue is thinking that this would be sold as a component, not actual pads that I place myself in a footprint.